# How to solve this error: build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:30: error: Build failed

Tags: android, custom-rom

I have a pixel 5 and this is the first time im building a custom rom.

```
In file included from build/make/core/main.mk:1358:
build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:30: error: Build failed.
13:01:45 ckati failed with: exit status 1
```

Im at the compiling process, I mostly tried to fix my errors through chatgpt and some developers but this time, Im not finding any fix.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit `build/envsetup.sh` and add `export DISABLE_ARTIFACT_PATH_REQUIREMENTS="true"`

You can add this line above `# The Gcc Toolchain does not xxxxxxx` it could be around line 9 to 11 or anywhere as you like. Close ssh load again do. `. build/envsetup.sh` & continue the build bingo!

Edit: Or just add `DISABLE_ARTIFACT_PATH_REQUIREMENTS := true`  in you device trees file BoardConfigCustom.mk`

Cheers ;)